# Merge two commits which are in pull request already

Tags: merge, github, commit, git-pull, pull-request

I was working only on my master branch (silly, I know!) and I pushed the commit to my repo and then opened a pull request against upstream.

Someone wanted me to fix this commit so I've done it and made another commit with pull request but now, there is pull request with 2 commits - how merge that commits together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly (not entirely sure) the word you are looking for is "squash":

[Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-can-i-squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)